# Dependent Dropdown lists in SugarCRM 6.4

Tags: drop-down-menu, sugarcrm, custom-fields, lead

I have added a couple of custom fields in leads module from the studio. I am trying to implement dependency on the dropdown lists using the this [tutorial](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/06/09/learning-sugar-logic-dynamic-dropdown-subindustry-field/) but somehow it doesn't seem to work. I have checked it over and again my code is the same as in tutorial but its not working. I am using sugar 6.4 community edition could it be possible that the particular method in the tutorial doesn't work for SugarCRM 6.4. Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sugar Community Edition doesn't have Sugar Logic, which is required for Dependent Dropdowns. Sugar Logic is only in the commercial editions of SugarCRM ( Pro, Corp, Ent, Ult )

Comment: How can I achieve what I am looking for ?